# Nested sorting in dimension hierarchies (Tableau)

Tags: sorting, nested, tableau-api, hierarchy, dimension

I am working on a vizualisation in Tableau that has dimension hierarchy (Product category, product sub-category, product type etc.) sorted descending by number of orders. I want my viz to show by default only first product level (product category) sorted the same way, but give an option to drill down (using "+" on the dimension) to detailed product levels and using nested sorting (again, descending by number of orders).

[superstore data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKBWv.png)

I tried using nested sorting option for each product level, but when I drill up and down again, the sorting is wrong again, as if it clears out. I cannot find an option to keep them fixed unless I keep all product levels visible in the viz (without drill-down option).

Does anyone know how can I do it? I tried also different ways of indexing and ranking calculations, but nothing seem to work. I know there is one option to combine hierarchy dimensions and using sorting option on them, but it keeps the viz really untidy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Tableau will always sort based on the left most column.  With the [newer nested sorting](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/sortgroup_sorting_computed_howto.htm#create-a-filtered-nested-sort) you can more easily do a secondary sorting.  However, when you expand up/down hierarchies like you are noting the formatting might not be retained.

The "classic" way to do this is to create a Rank by number of orders (sounds like you were close on this one).  `rank(COUNT([Order ID]),'desc')`.  Make this a discrete measure and put it to the left of all the other dimensions.

[image: Fixed Sorting]

To clean it up, you can uncheck "Show Header" on the rank pill.

[image: Hide header]

And if you expand/collapse the hierarchy, it keeps the sorting... Final product:

[image: Final sorting]

EDIT: Here is another way to try to accomplish this.  It seems to work for 3 levels but starts to break down after that.  (It also didn't seem to work well on grouped dimensions.)

1. Expand the hierarchy to all three levels.
2. On each dimension, enforce a sort order of Count of Order ID Descending.

[image: Sort button]

[image: Sort parameters]

Comment: thank you @tagyoureit for your post! I got to the same point in ranking actually, but this solution still does not give me exactly the look of the viz as I would like it to be. Ranking helps in sorting count of orders on all levels, but when I drill down, the viz shows Category label per each Sub-Category, which makes the viz untidy. Sorry if I haven't specified it before, but I was looking to have a ranking from highest to lowest no. of orders per Category, and ranking sorts them regardless of Cat. level. Even editing table calculations does not give me the answer I am looking for. Any ideas?

Comment: I added another method which seems to work well for up to 3 levels of hierarchy.  Hopefully you don't need more than that.  If you do, using actions to drill up/down using multiple sheets instead of within the same table would work better overall.